# Deserialize to Object with a List

Tags: c#, json, list, windows-phone-7, json.net

Im trying to parse an JSON response string to my class objects.. I can't figure this out and i  need some help with this.

I use the json.net reference but i cant't find what i'm looking for :(

my json:

```
{

"@companyName": "Company Name",
"@version": "1.0",
"@generatedDate": "3/1/10 2:10 PM",
"application": [
    {
        "@name": "Application #1 name",
        "@apiKey": "1234",
        "@createdDate": "2010-03-01",
        "@platform": "Platform name"
    },
    {
        "@name": "Application #1 name",
        "@apiKey": "1234",
        "@createdDate": "2010-03-01",
        "@platform": "Platform name"
    }
]
}
```

my root class for the json is:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string companyName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string generatedDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public List<Application> application { get; set; }
}
```

my sub class (list of applications):

```
public class Application
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string apiKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string createdDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string platform { get; set; }
}
```

To parse it i have the following code now:

```
      JObject obj = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
      applications = new RootObject
            {
                companyName = (string) obj["companyName"],
                version = (string) obj["version"],
                generatedDate = (string) obj["generatedDate"],
                application = ???????? (how to make a list here?)

            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your class definitions as follows

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("@companyName")]
    public string companyName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@version")]
    public string version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@generatedDate")]
    public string generatedDate { get; set; }

    public List<Application> application { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    [JsonProperty("@name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@apiKey")]
    public string apiKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@createdDate")]
    public string createdDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@platform")]
    public string platform { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize

```
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myjson);
```

Comment: Good catch on the '@' characters L.B.  I didn't even notice them when I was working on my answer. :)

Comment: Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1
[Application]

Comment: It works fine at my machine but you can try also `public Application[] application { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

A project I work on occasionally uses Json.Net.  It's a wonderful library.
I would use the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method instead.

In your case I would try something like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString);
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: Im getting an error at the application list :(

Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [Application]

Comment: @user917769 I got it to work in a test app.  I had to add the extra param to the JsonProperty attributes like in L.B's answer though to get this example to work with the json from this post.

Comment: or you could remove the '@' characters from the json so the json property names match the class property names

Comment: i will try for the coming hour

Comment: for me its not working at the moment... maybe it has to do something with serialize? is it possible that you post your code examples?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6799/discussion-between-jdonley83-and-user917769)

Comment: the problem was that when the array in the json has only one item, it wont show the [ ] characters.. so the api is broken or something! But i know the problem now :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code and report back any issues:

```
RootObject applications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
```

Comment: Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Flurry_Analytics.classes.Application]'.

Comment: i cant mark it as Serializable because its not possible in Windows Phone 7 Silverlight