# Deserializing JSON One-To-Many Relationship via an array of strings

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a list of objects from an array of strings that contains a corresponding string and a value inherited from the parent object. I have the following abridged JSON Output:

```
{
   "sku":"1234-SKU",
   
   "divisions":[
    "Division 1",
    "Division 2",
    "Division 3",
    "Division 4",
    "Finals Division"
   ]
}
```

I have a `Compeititon` class and a `Division` class that is abridged as follows:

```
public class Competition
{
    [JsonProperty("sku")]
    public string Sku;
    [JsonProperty("divisions")]
    public virtual List<Division> Divisions;
}

public class Division
{
    // Sku from parent object
    public string CompetitionSku;

    // Would be value from "divisions" array
    public string Name;
}
```

Using the example JSON output, I would get one Competition object with a Sku of "1234-SKU" and a list of 5 division objects, each has a sku "1234-SKU" and Name values of "Division 1", "Division 2", and so on.

I had originally created a `List<string>` for the JSON serializer to populate, then create Division objects by iterating through the list. Is there a way to correctly populate the Division object without needing to create a "carrier list"? Ideally, I think I can do this through a custom `JsonConverter` class, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: [Deserialize to Object with a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896924/deserialize-to-object-with-a-list) seems to be what you want.

Comment: @metacubed That's close and unless I'm being silly, that's not my situation. The only data I have in the "divisions" list in the JSON output is the Name value that goes into the Division object and I need to pass the "sku" value to the Division object.

Comment: Hm.. yeah I see. You don't have a wrapper there so you will probably need custom code like you mention.

Comment: @metacubed That's what I figured. I've tried mucking about with the `JsonConverter`, but I haven't found anything that would get me on track - do you know anything that could get me started? I can deserialize the list, but the reader is forward access only so I can't backtrack and get the Sku value. Is there a way for me to "restart" the `JsonReader`? Or, is the original Json string buried within the serializer or reader? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by creating a custom `JsonConverter` for the `Competition` class. I have to iterate through it "manually", but I have access to the whole object that way. When I get to the array of divisions, I deserialize it as a `List<string>>` and then iterate through the list to create the `Division` object and plugging in the already parsed `Competition.Sku`.